# How to handle mouse, touch, and pointer events in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, gestures, pointer-events

It's now 2017 and I find it a real pain to deal with all these different input methods (mouse, touch, pointers) in today's browsers. But just handling mouse events too often doesn't work out anymore when developing a HTML5/JS cross browser/platform app. Since AngularJS is a pretty solid, state-of-the-art framework, I would expect it supports me somehow in this matter. Or am I wrong?

Chrome 55+ supports now the [Pointer Event API](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/). For the browsers not yet supporting it (or do not want to support it, yes, I'm pointing at you Safari), there are [polyfills](https://github.com/jquery/PEP) available. So this looks like the way to go.

In my Angular app, I just want to do something like:

```
<div ng-pointerdown="vm.handlePointerDown()"
     ng-pointerup="vm.handlePointerUp()"
     ng-pointercancel="vm.handlePointerCancel()"
     ng-pointermove="vm.handlePointerMove()"
     ng-pointerover="vm.handlePointerOver()"
     ng-pointerout="vm.handlePointerOut()">
</div>
```

And then I want to forget all about ng-mouse* handlers and not care about writing custom touchstart, touchend, etc. handlers I have to subscribe to in parallel.

Is there any plan for Angular to add native support for this? Or is there any 3rd party Angular library supporting this in a proper way?

I know I can write everything myself, but for me this seems so fundamental that it should receive the desired attention from the framework or the ecosystem around it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14634#issuecomment-220281576

Comment: See this: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/eventhandlers/mouseevents/

Comment: A couple months ago I worked on a "draw in module" for project developers. I believe the guys there used this jquery plugin. https://github.com/deepsweet/jquery-pointerevents . I know its not a angular only solution, but will leave it here.

Comment: @Ankh Thanks for the link, added a comment there.

Comment: @S.Visser Thanks for the link, unfortunately looks like it is not actively maintained, but maybe something to build up on.